# C or C++ for embedded code, in Keil, STM32

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, stm32

I am writing C code for STM32 in Keil.
But C is not enough sometimes (for example scoped enums).

I want to write C++ on Keil. But some embedded developers are told, "C++ is not robust in Keil, better to use C". Is this true?

`

Comment: All depends on how you code.  The C language may not be robust depending on the implementation.  Anybody can write bad code, regardless of language.  Writing correct and robust code is difficult.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i mean " is c++ compiler trustable in keil"

Comment: The C++ language provides more support for robust and correct code, such as *references*.  A reference must exist when passed to a function; no such guarantees with C and pointers.

Comment: You will need to contact Keil or search the web to see how much of the C++ language (and which version) that Keil implements.

Comment: To me good programmer can write robust code. Even implementation in C++ is robust, as novice programmer is more chance of screwing robustness in C++. I have using own implementation of scope enum in C, embedded system.

Comment: Companies dealing in "embedded software", mine for example, often also need "safety", "real time". They also might stress the part of "embedded" which is governed by "very little available resources". They are very skeptical concerning the compatibility of C++ (or its difference to C, e.g. OOP) with these requirements. Often they finally give in and allow C++, but with many restrictions which spoil the fun. I think the "c++ is not robust" might mean something like this. (Note I have no idea what "keil" is.) Even though it reduces my fun, I see some reason in this opinion.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer there is no scoped enums in c , this support came after c++v11 . In embeded , developers have very poor sources , for example stm32f030c6 has only 32kb flash memory and 4kb ram . code size also important for this topic.

Comment: Who is telling embedded developers that *"C++ is not robust in Keil,"* - a citation is required for that.  In what way is it nor "robust", and what do you even mean by "robust".

Comment: i mean trustable. I have been developing with c more than 6 years. I am an electronical engineer. Can i trust c++ as c in mdk-arm compiler? and do you recommend C++ for this compiler? @Clifford

Comment: @Metinkundakçıoğlu : It is a very mature compiler.  The latest MDK-ARM in fact includes two compilers ARMCC v5.x and ARMCC v6.x.  The latter is LLVM based rather than RVCT and probably best for new projects, and probably has better C++11 support.

Comment: Keil is certifying its ARM 6.6 compiler, as they did with their ARMCC 5 compiler. Biggest issue is that Keil uVision does not support code browsing if you use any compiler other than ARMCC 5.0x. It basically become an IDE inferior to Notepad++. Debugging actually works fine for the most part though (tried with C++14).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keil is the name of a company (wholly owned by ARM), not a compiler.  Keil's MDK-ARM uses ARM's RealView and more recently LLVM based compilers.  They are high quality C an C++ compilers.  Support for C++11 is [recent](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1407404265784.htm) if incomplete, but if you regard C as a viable alternative, C++11 is perhaps not a priority.

Where MDK-ARM does fall down perhaps in terms of C++ support is in its debugger, its support for C++ is not perfect, but I have found that to be true of a number of C++ tool-chains for embedded environments.

I have been developing for STM32 using Keil's MDK-ARM almost exclusively using C++ for 8 years.

Comment: that is interesting, a little while before they acquired Keil they acquired Allant which had a better debugger, for the debugger, the RealView tools came directly from that change, to a better debugger.  After acquiring Keil a reduced RVCT compiler was included, but not as the main, now it sounds like they have gone a couple of steps past that...stemming from a good/better debugger to the present.  I run linux primarily so cant play with Keil.  Used the two toolchains before RVCT and they produced fairly good/fast code (better than gcc and gcc has not gotten much better, clang is slower).

Comment: If you are saying the weakness is connecting high level code to stepping or breakpointing with respect to the C++ source, code, yeah that is not trivial (no one to one connection) and the better the optimizer the worse that connection is if there is a connection at all.  C bad C++ that much worse as a general programming problem, so I would expect all debuggers to fall down to some extent.  Keil has been around since the dark ages and keeps on trucking, so they must be doing something right...

Comment: I have to agree the C++ debugging in Keil is not very good. Having worked with Keil for many years with both C and C++ I used to think it was a good tool. However more recently spending a lot of time with IAR and Eclipse/GCC based environments I think that IAR is a far superior environment as well as a better compiler. The GCC compiler is also very good, but I am not so keen on Eclipse (I have not really used these for C++ though).

Comment: I should add though that the Keil C++ compiler is reliable and would trust it.

Comment: @old_timer : The biggest issue with the debugger is that it seems confused by namespaces on occasions.  Most issues have work-arounds - I'd still rather be using it than GDB!  Clang slow to compile, or generates slow code?  I'd be surprised if the latter, and long build times is a coffee break, so what's not to like!

Comment: @old_timer : I would never expect the debug experience to make much sense on optimised code in any debugger - even VC++ which has about the best debugger I can imagine.

Comment: @Clifford fully understand and agree, kind of the point.  also note that just because they acquired allant doesnt mean that that debugger went into Keil, or that it was even a good debugger, I dont know the Keil history on that you clearly would know a lot more than me.  I also never use a debugger have no use for one, so again, you would clearly know a lot more than me on that topic...